# GPUImage blend filters

Tags: ios, gpuimage, ios7.1

I'm trying to apply a blend filters to 2 images.
I've recently updated `GPUImage` to the last version.
To make things simple I've modified the example SimpleImageFilter.
Here is the code:

```
  UIImage * image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PGSImage_0000.jpg"];
    UIImage * image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PGSImage_0001.jpg"];
    twoinputFilter = [[GPUImageColorBurnBlendFilter alloc] init];
    sourcePicture1 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image1 ];
    sourcePicture2 = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image2 ];
    [sourcePicture1 addTarget:twoinputFilter];
    [sourcePicture1 processImage];
    [sourcePicture2 addTarget:twoinputFilter];
    [sourcePicture2 processImage];
    UIImage * image = [twoinputFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

The image returned is `nil`.Applying some breakpoints I can see that the filter fails inside the method `- (CGImageRef)newCGImageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` the problem is that the `framebufferForOutput` is nil.I'm using simulator.
I don't get why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that I was missing this command, as written in the documentation for still image processing:

> Note that for a manual capture of an image from a filter, you need to
>   set -useNextFrameForImageCapture in order to tell the filter that
>   you'll be needing to capture from it later. By default, GPUImage
>   reuses framebuffers within filters to conserve memory, so if you need
>   to hold on to a filter's framebuffer for manual image capture, you
>   need to let it know ahead of time.

```
[twoinputFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
```

Comment: Yeah, I explain why I made that change here: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2014/03/17/switching-gpuimage-use-cached-framebuffers , but it's not all that obvious. I'm seeing if there's a better, more transparent way of handling this, but for now this is what I'm making people do.

Comment: I think that in this way it really performs betters profiling it. My app  requires a lot of filtered images and memory occupation was a big deal. The fact that the explanation was really at the bottom of the document and title Still Images wasn't helpful, since english isn't my mother tongue, I do not know why but I've associated it to AVcaptureStillImage and not just simple pictures. I you do not mind maybe bringing some changelog or explanation at the top of the git page, would be really helpful.

Comment: This question is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551434/gpuimage-apply-filter-to-a-buffer-of-images/22616828#22616828 I've already answered it, but if you have time to take a look and say if I'm correct it would be wonderful. Thx, andrea