# GPUImage cannot blend opacity filtered image with others

Tags: ios, image-processing, gpuimage

I want to use GPUImage to adjust the opacity of a image, and use this image ,blend with other pics.
here is how i use:

```
        GPUImagePicture *originPic = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image];
        UIImage *copyImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
        GPUImageOpacityFilter *opacity = [[GPUImageOpacityFilter alloc] init];
        [opacity setOpacity:0.5];
        UIImage *opacityAdjusted = [opacity imageByFilteringImage:copyImage];
        GPUImagePicture *opacityAdjustedPic = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:opacityAdjusted]
        GPUImageScreenBlendFilter *screenBlend = [[GPUImageScreenBlendFilter alloc] init];
        [originPic addTarget:screenBlend];
        [opacityAdjusted addTarget:addTarget:screenBlend];
        [originPic processImage];
        [opacityAdjusted processImage];
        UIImage *output = [screenBlend imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

I've displayed the output but the result is the same as "originPic blend with copyPic", what i want is "originPic blend with 0.5opacityCopyPic"

Answer (score -1):

Brad has changed some mechanism to improve memory usage. If you want to filter still images with two input filters try like this answer [GPUImage blend filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580432/gpuimage-blend-filters/22589045#22589045)